# RascalMPL and Rust Lang Interoperation

Tags: rascal

I want to implement a CLI(command-line interface) in rust-lang to drive a rascal language project for reverse engineering and code generation, how do you advice I go about it?

*Links to projects, documents and repo that explains/answers this will be very much appreciated :-)*

Answer (score 0):

Three directions; either go JNI, link rust code to the jvm that's running rascal. You can use jlink and jdeps to get a slim binary that links the rust library to a JVM.

The second would be using Graal VM to run rust directly in the JVM.

Finally, just implement your CLI inn rascal. Main functions in Rascal with keyword parameters automatically get a proper CLI interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I build the rascal language project as a Java project, in order to be able to do the interoperation? Need a bit more clarity.

Comment: It's a maven project, so `mvn package` will produce a jar file that contains everything you need from the rascal language.

Comment: So you could make another maven project that depends on rascal. Then use mvn to use Graal or jni to link your rust code.

Comment: Sorry could you expantiate a bit more on the second reply? How do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried running `mvn package` in the rascal project to generate the rascal artefacts, but when I tried to call the rascal jar from a java project it didn't work. I think am doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe have a look at some example projects: flybytes and clair both use and extend rascal with rascal and java code.

Comment: If you know how to make rust interact with java, then the connection to rascal is the next step; probably easier.

Comment: Running mvn package doesn't include the `RASCAL.MF` file in the output JAR. Is that normal?

Comment: I have this in my pom: `<resource>
                                <directory>.</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                        <include>META-INF/RASCAL.MF</include>
                                        <include>src/**/*.rsc</include>
                                        <include>doc/**/*.md</include>
                                </includes>
                        </resource>
`

Comment: That worked, thanks.